# Directx 11 - Are all Vertices from a vertex buffer pushed through to the vertex shader or just indexed ones?

Tags: c++, directx-11

In Directx 11 when you set the vertex and index buffers

```
_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
```

will all the vertices in the vertex buffer go through the graphics pipeline or only the ones indexed by the index buffer?

Answer (score 0):

To be short, only the index referenced vertices are pushed through the pipeline.  As the pipeline vertex context is generated in the vertex shader (vertex identified by index and read in). Also, because you are using indicies, the caching is more efficient, as the pipline uses the index as a reference into the cache so it doesn't have to process the same vertex twice (unless a cache miss occurs).

Therefore, indexed mesh(s) gain a performance benefit when over non indexed (if the indices are not a 1 to 1 mapping).